# Change filename while exporting reports ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017

I am using Report server subscription to mail the reports but I want to generate export excel with the different name. Currently I am getting excel filename same as report name

I am using SSRS 2017 and also I didn't find any filename option in data driven subscrition

Comment: No.. out of the box there is no way to set a file name for EMAIL data driven subscriptions .It's annoying and a repeated request from my customers to..

Comment: Thanks, Harry for a response.  
Do you know any other way to do it ? 
I there any way to generate a report by calling it in SQL script. I want to collect logs of the sent mails and generated report as well.